# C : Vec of structures

Tags: c, vector, struct

I want to create a vec of structures. This is my struct:

```
    typedef struct item {
        char *name;
        int acc;
    } *Item;
```

I tried:

```
    Item vec = (Item) malloc(sizeof(Item)*max);
```

max is previously defined. I get this `error: initializer element is not constant`

Comment: `typedef struct item { ... } * Item;` Is a terrible idea.

Comment: Think what `sizeof(Item)` does, given it is a pointer type...

Comment: @EugeneSh. One of the reasons why my comment is sooo true.

Comment: Is `vec` a global variable? (btw, I agree with iharob that you should never typedef a pointer.) And there's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: BTW, the error message is completely unrelated to the code you posted. If you really want help, post the code.

Comment: @iharob originally we were going for what is suggested in the answer. But on the tips for this project it was said that the way that we used "allows a propper abstraction". That's the only reason why we used it.

Comment: @iharob and no, the error message is not completely unrelated to the code I posted `draft3.c:28:12: error: initializer element is not constant
 Item vec = (Item) malloc(sizeof(Item)*max);`

Comment: @user3386109 yes, vec is a global variable. So it's impossible to do what I was trying?

Comment: Yup, local variables can be initialized with function calls, but global variables cannot. Globals can only be initialized with compile-time constants. If `max` is a constant, then `vec` could be declared as an array: `struct item vec[max];`. Otherwise, you need to call `malloc` at some point after the value of `max` has been determined.

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — the short answer is "No"; the marginally longer answer is "No, unless perhaps it is a function pointer".

Answer (score 1):

Change it by:

```
typedef struct item {
    char *name;
    int acc;
} Item;
```

(no pointer) and then do sizeof(struct item) or sizeof(Item). Then

```
Item *vec = malloc(sizeof(Item) * max);
```

Comment: A simple solution that will always work is `sizeof(*vec)`. But `typedef`ing a pointer is in genearal problematic.

Comment: @iharob, agree with your statement.

Comment: [No cast in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) - See this Q&A

Comment: Thank you. I always did cast for malloc but this makes sense.